# how to make one from the the following two queries

Tags: join, sql-server-2012

i have two queries:

the first one query is:

```
SELECT sale.saleid, 
   sale.totalpaid, 
   item.itemname         AS item, 
   stock.saleprice       AS Price, 
   invoice.qty, 
   sale.discount, 
   invoice.saleprice     AS [invoice saleprice], 
   cetegory.catname      AS [Cateogory], 
   cetegory.subcat       AS [Sub Catgry], 
   vehicle.vehicle_name  AS [Vehicle], 
   vehicle.vehicle_model AS [Model], 
   item.model_number     AS [Part No.], 
   sale.date, 
   stock.size, 
   sale.customerid 
FROM   invoice 
       JOIN item 
         ON invoice.itemid = item.itemid 
       JOIN sale 
         ON invoice.saleid = sale.saleid 
       JOIN stock 
         ON item.itemid = stock.itemid 
       JOIN cetegory 
         ON item.catid = cetegory.catid 
       JOIN vehicle 
         ON item.vehicleid = vehicle.vehicleid 
WHERE  sale.saleid = 5
```

and the second query is:

```
SELECT customer.customername, 
       customer.customercontact, 
       customer.customeraddress, 
       account.account_type 
FROM   account 
       JOIN customer 
         ON customer.customerid = account.customerid
```

Now  i want to combine these two queries by customer id because i have "custome id" in sale table

Comment: What is the purpose of `c#` tag?

Comment: because i use this query in c#

Comment: @Mrkhan where you call a query from doesn't affect the query itself. As for the question itself, what do you mean "combine"? Why not just join all tables in a single query? What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: i just want to combine the above two query into one single query.. that's it

Comment: Exactly i want to join all tables in a single query. but don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CTE and then join both:

```
 WITH CUST
 AS
  (SELECT customer.customername, 
   customer.customercontact, 
   customer.customeraddress, 
   account.account_type ,
   customer.customerid
 FROM   account 
   JOIN customer 
     ON customer.customerid = account.customerid 
 ),

 SALES
 AS
 (
 SELECT sale.saleid, 
 sale.totalpaid, 
 item.itemname         AS item, 
 stock.saleprice       AS Price, 
 invoice.qty, 
 sale.discount, 
 invoice.saleprice     AS [invoice saleprice], 
 cetegory.catname      AS [Cateogory], 
 cetegory.subcat       AS [Sub Catgry], 
 vehicle.vehicle_name  AS [Vehicle], 
 vehicle.vehicle_model AS [Model], 
 item.model_number     AS [Part No.], 
 sale.date, 
 stock.size, 
 sale.customerid 
 FROM   invoice 
   JOIN item 
     ON invoice.itemid = item.itemid 
   JOIN sale 
     ON invoice.saleid = sale.saleid 
   JOIN stock 
     ON item.itemid = stock.itemid 
   JOIN cetegory 
     ON item.catid = cetegory.catid 
   JOIN vehicle 
     ON item.vehicleid = vehicle.vehicleid 
 WHERE  sale.saleid = 5 
 )

SELECT * FROM CUST
LEFT JOIN SALES
ON CUST.customerid = SALES.customerid
```

Comment: A CTE (Common Table Expression) is temporary result set that you can reference within another SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.  They were introduced in SQL Server version 2005. A CTE always returns a result set.  They are used to simplify queries, for example, you could use one to eliminate a derived table from the main query body

Comment: hey dude your query works fine there are issue now can you help me out

Comment: 1) i return only 'Asia Dryer 600' and it show for the item too. i want to skip this for other which has not return 2) The paided, debit and discount amount has been paid according to one saleid and it show me every same sale id i want when the sale id is same then only first rows of having the same sale id, these (paided, debit and discount) amount show and for else it should be zero or null

Comment: see the image https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/problem-in-sql-join/m-p/2419597/thread-id/1035?attachment-id=38671